# .NET Remoting and HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, appdomain

We have a plugin system where the plugin code runs on a separate AppDomain from the main process, using .NET remoting for the objects to communicate.

One class is similar to HttpContext.Current (which also suffers from the problem) (edit, the actual implementation):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current != null)
                return HttpContext.Current.Items["MyClassInstance"];
        }
        set
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current != null)
                HttpContext.Current.Items["MyClassInstance"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we have a communicating object which inherits from MarshalByRefObject:

```
public class CommunicatingClass : MarshalByRefObject, ICommunicatingClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyClass.Instance.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The CommunicatingClass is created on the main AppDomain, and works fine. Then, there's the plugin class, which is created on its AppDomain, and given an instance of the CommunicatingClass:

```
public class PluginClass
{
    public void DoSomething(ICommunicatingClass communicatingClass)
    {
        communicatingClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that even though CommunicatingClass resides on the main appdomain (verified with the Immediate Window), all of the static data such as MyClass.Instance and HttpContext.Current have disappeared and are null. I have a feeling that MyClass.Instance is somehow being retrieved from the plugin AppDomain, but am unsure how to resolve this.

I saw another question that suggested `RemotingServices.Marshal`, but that did not seem to help, or I used it incorrectly. Is there a way that the CommunicatingClass can access all static methods and properties like any other class in the main AppDomain?

Edit:

The PluginClass is given an instance like this:

```
public static PluginClass Create()
{
    var appDomain = GetNewAppDomain();
    var instance = (PluginClass)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assembly, type);
    instance.Communicator = new CommunicatingClass();
    return instance;
}
```

Edit 2:

Might have found the source of the problem. MyClass.Instance is stored in HttpContext.Current.Items (see above edit).

Is there any way at all that HttpContext.Current can access the correct HttpContext? I'm still wondering why, even though it is being run in HttpContext.Current's AppDomain, CommunicatingClass.DoSomething, when calling MyClass.Instance, retrieves stuff from PluginClass' AppDomain (if that makes any sense).

Comment: In case you didn't know: Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: It might help if you included the code you use to get a reference to communicatingClass in the PluginClass app domain.

Comment: @John Saunders, How does WCF work with cross-appdomain communication? It makes sense when the client and server are separated, but doesn't seem like it would be as easy as transparent remoting proxies in this case. I've never worked with WCF though, just looked at it.

Comment: @Snea: it works. It completely replaces Remoting.

Comment: @John Saunders, Do you have articles or other questions talking about how to migrate cross-appdomain communicating using remoting to WCF, or should I ask another question to that extent?

Comment: @Snea: no, I don't know of specific articles, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf.

Comment: @Snea: If you are looking to have a totally dynamic plug-in, you probably won't be able to get that working in WCF.  You can use interfaces in your WCF method signatures, but you have to "register" all specific implementations in order for it to work.

Comment: @John: that's not the case. There are DI frameworks that work well with WCF. I believe I've seen articles indicating that MEF works as well.

Comment: @John: I'd love to see a way around the KnownType issue.  Can you link something?

Comment: @John: you mean returning plug-in types from a service? Fundamentally impossible. How would the caller know what you're returning? How would it know how to deserialize it?

Comment: @John: Edit - removing, don't want to hijack this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So my co-worker and I worked this out, finally, with a bunch of help from Reflector.

The main problem is that HttpContext.Current is null when accessed via a remoting call.

The HttpContext.Current property is stored in an interesting manor. A few nested setters down, you reach `CallContext.HostContext`. This is a static object property on a `CallContext`.

When the CallContext is set, it first checks if the value is an [`ILogicalThreadAffinitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.ilogicalthreadaffinative.aspx).

- If it is, it stores the value in the current thread's `LogicalCallContext`.
- If it's not, it stores the value in the current thread's `IllogicalCallContext`.

`HttpContext` is **not** an `ILogicalThreadAffinitive`, so it is stored in the `IllogicalCallContext`.

---

**Then, there's remoting.**

We didn't dig too far in to its source, but what it does was inferred from some other functions.

When a call is made *to* a remote object *from* a different AppDomain, the call is not directly proxied to the original thread, running in the exact same execution context.

First, the `ExecutionContext` of the original thread (the one containing `HttpContext.Current`) is captured, via `ExecutionContext.Capture` (more in this in a bit).

Then, the `ExecutionContext` returned from `Capture` is passed as the first argument to `ExecutionContext.Run`, esentially forming the code:

```
Delegate myRemoteCall; //Assigned somewhere else in remoting
ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext.Capture(), x => { myRemoteCall() }, null);
```

Then, completely transparently, your code in the remote object is accessed.

Unfortunately, `HttpContext.Current` is not captured in `ExecutionContext.Capture()`.

Here lies the essential difference between an `IllogicalCallContext` and a `LogicalCallContext`.

`Capture` creates a brand-new `ExecutionContext`, essentially copying all of the members (such as the `LogicalCallContext`) in to the new object. But, it does **not** copy the `IllogicalCallContext`.

So, since `HttpContext` is not an `ILogicalThreadAffinative`, it *cannot* be captured by `ExecutionContext.Capture`.

---

**The solution?**

HttpContext is not a MarshalByRefObject or [Serializable] (probably for good reason), so it cannot be passed in to the new AppDomain.

**But**, it can cross `ExecutionContext`s without problem.

So, in the main AppDomain's MarshalByRefObject which is given as a proxy to the other AppDomain, in the constructor give it the instance of `HttpContext.Current`.

Then, in each method call of the new object (unfortunately), run:

```
private HttpContext _context;
private void SyncContext()
{
    if(HttpContext.Current == null)
        HttpContext.Current = _context;
}
```

And it will be set without problem. Since HttpContext.Current is tied to the `IllogicalCallContext` of the `ExecutionContext`, it will not bleed in to any other threads that ASP.NET might create, and will be cleaned up when the copy `ExecutionContext` is disposed.

(I could be wrong about much of this, though. It's all speculation and reflection)

Comment: I thought your problem was with MyClass, not HttpContect.Current.  Perhaps you should modify your question.  Or are you saying in this answer that MyClass is still not accessible?

Comment: MyClass was stored in the HttpContext, I found out. I'll change the title.

Comment: Very good explanation. Are you passing in HttpContext.Current to the constructor of the MarshalByRefObject as an argument in the appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap call? Or are you creating an instance of the MarshalByRefObject and then somehow passing it into the other AppDomain?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to derive MyClass from MarshalByRefObject as well.

Comment: Yep, all classes that depend on a specific reference to a remote object (i.e. a singleton in this case) need to extend from `MarshalByRefObject` as well, otherwise they get lost on the other side of the app domain.

Comment: Odd, I had tried that before, and still got the same problem. I'll fiddle around with it some more. Also, why would this be? If the CommunicatingClass instance is on the same AppDomain as MyClass, wouldn't it be visible right there? Or is the CommunicatingClass somewhere "in between" domains?

Comment: See above edit. MyClass being a MarshalByRefObject probably does fix its own case, but HttpContext.Current can't be a MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: At this point, you should start to question your design. Isn't MyClass static? If so, it's not stored in HttpContext.Current.

Comment: I'm sure there are design issues here. The issue now is either "accessing" HttpContext.Current from CommunicatingClass, or finding another way to access MyClass.Current from CommunicatingClass.